# changing webclient response time

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, webclient

I want to use facebook like button in my website. as most of my visitors are from Iran and facebook is filtered in Iran, if somebody comes from Iran, the like button gets filtered and the page gets very ugly. what I have thought to prevent this is to use webclient to try to connect to facebook. if successful, I place the like button, otherwise I don't:

```
string fb_result="failed";
WebClient webclient= new  WebClient();
try{
fb_result=webclient.DownloadString("http://www.fabebook.com");
}
catch{
 fb_result="failed"; //if its being filtered exception is raised
}
```

the in my html:

```
<%if(fb_result)!="failed"){%>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.mysite.com" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
<%}%>
```

this works fine but the problem is, when webclient is unable to connect, it takes to much time to raise the error. is there any way to make webclient try for a shorter time and if not able to connect raise the error faster.

by the way, any other ways to check if connection to facebook is possible or not is appeciated. as this might not be the only way to check it.

Comment: This won't work, WebClient is being executed on the server, not your clients, so it will always succeed. Instead display the Like button using a client script that checks for Facebook first.

Comment: but how can i check it? ajax won't work, if i load it in an iframe, i won't be able to check its document. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: An AJAX technique will work: it will report an error. If it succeeds then you add the Like button. You don't need to actually query the DOM of Facebook (unless Iran's filter sends a bogus response; I don't know how it works).

Comment: yes it redirects to a filter page, let me check if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in my comments, the `WebClient` code you've written will not work because it is executed on the server, so it will attempt to connect to Facebook using your webserver's connection, which will always succeed (unless your webhost goes offline).

The best approach is to have an AJAX request made by your page when it loads in the browser. It should make a request for a known resource on Facebook (such as their homepage, or the "Like" image itself). Your AJAX response handler will then load the rest of the Facebook client scripts if, and only if, the response is as-expected. If you test it by requesting the Like image then you just need to check the response's content-type (i.e. ensure it's `image/png`); if the response has a non-200 status code or if the request times-out then you don't load the Facebook scripts.

Comment: in both cases (filtered and not) the response is 0. I think its because its not in my domain

Comment: `0` is not a valid response code. Please post the code you're using.

Comment: var xmlhttp;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {               
                    alert(xmlhttp.status);
                    alert(xmlhttp.readyState);
                }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.facebook.com/index.php",true);
                xmlhttp.send();

Comment: the link starts with http://www. here in comment its censored. just want you to know that the link is correct